# Asp.net - Could not load type 'MyNameSpace.Reporting.UI._Default'

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I have one aspx page (`Project.aspx`) and one `aspx.cs` code (`Project.aspx.cs`). This website is installed on Client side, this works fine at the before time. But nowadays this cannot work and throw yellow page as following:

---

```
Server Error in '/mywebcom' Application.

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to 
service this request. 
Please review the following specific parse error details and 
modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'MyNameSpace.Reporting.UI._Default'.

Source Error: 


Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" EnableEventValidation="false" CodeBehind="Project.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyNameSpace.Reporting.UI._Default" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <%@ Register Src="controls/Search.ascx" TagName="Search" TagPrefix="uc1" %>

Source File: /myweb/tool/reporting/Project.aspx    Line: 1 

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5448; ASP.NET         

Version:2.0.50727.5456
```

---

Please help me something.
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Thsi bit:

```
Inherits="MyNameSpace.Reporting.UI._Default"
```

In your page directive is looking for a codebehind class called _Default.  Change this to match whatever the codebehind class is called.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
but these names are same, class name is _Default also.